# I am new to python I am getting stuck in a error: Exception: Invalid instance in App.root

Tags: python, kivy

I use VSCode and this is the code:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class RajdeepGrid():

    pass    

class RajdeepApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return RajdeepGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    RajdeepApp().run()
```

Now when I execute this after all imports this error occurs:
Exception: Invalid instance in App.root

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `class RajdeepGrid():` should inherit from a Kivy class, like `class RajdeepGrid(GridLayout):`.